# Будет ли CUDA код работать на других видеокартах?

Tags: cuda

Будет ли программа, использующая технологию CUDA работать в системах на видеокартах NVidia, не поддерживающих CUDA ? А в системах на видеокартах других производителей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотря как написана программа. В норме - не будет.

Comment: Что значит "как написана"?

Comment: Это значит, что программе, которая использует куду, нужна поддержка этой технологии. Если поддержки нет - прога не работает.
Костыли:   

 - сделать эмулятор куды.  
 - заставить программу саму проверять наличие куды. В случае отсутствия - стартовать по другому сценарию.

Answer (score 0):

Можно компилировать и запускать программу в режиме эмуляции, т.е. на CPU. Но работать будет, естественно, на порядок медленнее.